# Can only download 1000 runs' data from Weights and Biases

Tags: wandb

I have run and logged a sweep of experiments in Weights and Biases. I'm trying to download the details of the individual runs in a csv file by using the web panel. However, I see that I can only download 1000 runs (my experiment has 4000) total. Is there any way of getting around this? I tried using the API, but it takes excruciatingly long to download the files.

I am able to use filters to extract the data 1000 runs at a time, but this is very inconvenient as well.